# How to keep the capture of the previous window after closing another one?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making an application in which different windows open, and naturally, when the window is opened, the functionality of the previous window is not available until the current one closes.

It would seem that everything is fine, but for example: we open three windows - window_1, window_2, window_3 - one by one from each window. We see that when window_3 is active, all others are inactive. Next, we close the active window, and we see that suddenly, along with window_2, window_1 is also active.

How to solve this problem?

I wrote a simple code to fully understand this task:

```
from tkinter import *

class Second_Child_Win():

    def __init__(self):

        self.root = Toplevel()
        self.root.geometry('200x200')
        self.root.grab_set()

    def run(self, first_child_root):

        Button(self.root, text='Quit', command=self.root.destroy).pack()
        first_child_root.wait_window(self.root)


class First_Child_Win():

    def __init__(self):

        self.root = Toplevel()
        self.root.geometry('200x200')
        self.root.grab_set()

    def run(self, main_root):

        Button(self.root, text='click', command=self.open_new_win).pack()
        main_root.wait_window(self.root)

    def open_new_win(self):

        A = Second_Child_Win()
        A.run(self.root)


class Main():

    def __init__(self):

        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('200x200')

    def run(self):

        Button(self.root, text='click', command=self.open_new_win).pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def open_new_win(self):

        A = First_Child_Win()
        A.run(self.root)


A = Main()
A.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the decision is quite simple. Simply, after ending the session of the current window, I write `grab_set` again

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a `parent` parameter via the child classes' respective `__init__` medhods, e.g. `def __init__(self, parent): ...`, then set the master of the given `Toplevel` window to the same parent

Here's a quick example with a class I've called `StackWindow` that inherits from `Toplevel` directly and automatically pulls focus upon instantiation.

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):  # root window
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Root')
        self.window_a = StackWindow(self)  # parent = root window
        self.window_b = StackWindow(self.window_a)  # parent = window_a
        self.lower()  # for example - put the root window at the bottom of the stack


class StackWindow(tk.Toplevel):  # a.k.a. your 'child' windows
    def __init__(self, parent):  # this class will expect a 'parent' argument
        self.parent = parent
        super().__init__(self.parent)  # create a new Toplevel w/ the given parent
        self.tkraise()  # bring this window to the top of the stack
        self.grab_set()  # allow interaction with this window only


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

When you run this app, a root window will be created along with two child windows (both `Toplevel` objects), and you'll need to close them in the order they're created in order to interact with the next-lowest window in the stack.

Comment: Unfortunately, these methods do not work for me :-(